Linux .netcore service unable to start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
I have a basic .net core 8.0 app, on Oracle Linux. I am able to run the app manually, but running it as a service returns error.
This command runs the app succesfully;
$ /home/opc/.dotnet/dotnet /srv/macrodietapi/MacroDietAPI.dll

Starting the service;
$ sudo systemctl start MacroDietAPI.service
$ sudo systemctl status MacroDietAPI.service

Returns This Error

And my service looks like this;
[Unit]
Description=MacroDietAPI

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/srv/macrodietapi/
ExecStart=/home/opc/.dotnet/dotnet /srv/macrodietapi/MacroDietAPI.dll
User=opc
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=macrodietapi
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_ROOT=/home/opc/.dotnet

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I have tried lots of versions of the service file but none of them worked.
